# Bash: Associative array declared by `declare -A` not available outside of a function

Tags: bash, associative-array

Here, we initialize two associative arrays `arr_A` and `arr_B` in exactly the same way, but `arr_A` is initialized on the top-level, whereast `arr_B` is initialized inside of a function `foo`:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr_A
arr_A[bar]=42

function foo() {
  declare -A arr_B
  arr_B[bar]=58
  echo "content of arr_B inside foo = ${arr_B[@]}"
}
foo

echo "content of arr_A on top level = ${arr_A[@]}"
echo "content of arr_B on top level = ${arr_B[@]}"
```

Expected output:

```
content of arr_B inside foo = 58
content of arr_A on top level = 42
content of arr_B on top level = 58
```

Actual output:

```
content of arr_B inside foo = 58
content of arr_A on top level = 42
content of arr_B on top level =
```

Why is this happening?

Is there any way to initialize a new associative array inside of a function, and use it after the function has returned?

Comment: Regarding the duplicate: I agree that these two questions are essentially the same, still, my variant of the question is half as long, and doesn't require editing / reopening / rerunning everything twice. And it's not like the other question has thousand times more upvotes either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Because when used inside a function, [`declare`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare) has the semantics of `local` unless the `-g` flag is used.

> Is there any way to initialize a new associative array inside of a function, and use it after the function has returned?

Yes, use the `-g` flag for this purpose:

```
function foo() {
  declare -A -g arr_B
  arr_B[bar]=58
  echo "content of arr_B inside foo = ${arr_B[@]}"
}

foo
echo "content of arr_B on top level = ${arr_B[@]}"
```

Comment: @AndreyTyukin For "initializing" it you might also have to wipe it out: `foo() { unset arr_B; declare -gA arr_B; arr_B[a]=58; }`

Answer (score 1):

`declare` in a function defines a `local` variable, to define a global one :

```
    declare -gA arr_B
```